# need term frequency in new column of dataframe // scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql

I have this dataframe :

```
+----------+--------+---------+-------------+----+
|article_id|     sen|    token|          ner| pos|
+----------+--------+---------+-------------+----+
|         1|example1|Standford| Organisation| NNP|
|         1|example1|       is|            O|  VP|
|         1|example1|       is|     LOCATION| ADP|
|         2|example2|Standford|Organisation2|NNP2|
|         2|example2|       is|           O2| VP2|
|         2|example2|     good|    LOCATION2|ADP2|
+----------+--------+---------+-------------+----+
```

I need a new column called "term_frequency" which gives me:

- 2 in front of **is**
- and 1 in front of **Stanford**

  as I need to map them with number of times they occur in *article_id*.

I guess something like:

`df2.withColumn("termFrequency",'token.map(s => (s,1).reduceByKey(_ + _)))`  or creating new UDF.

dataframe schema is as follows:

```
root
 |-- article_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- sen: string (nullable = true)
 |-- token: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ner: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pos: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the results by a double group by on the two columns:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import Row
>>> lines = sc.textFile("data.txt")
>>> parts = lines.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
>>> articles = parts.map(lambda p: Row(article_id=int(p[0]), sen=p[1], token=p[2], ner=p[3], pos=p[4]))
>>> df = articles.toDF()

>>> df.count()
6

>>> df.groupBy("article_id", "token").count().show()
+----------+---------+-----+
|article_id|    token|count|
+----------+---------+-----+
|         1|Standford|    1|
|         1|       is|    2|
|         2|Standford|    1|
|         2|       is|    1|
|         2|     good|    1|
+----------+---------+-----+
```

You can register this new table as a table, and the original one as a table and perform a join to get a single table again:

```
>>> sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(df, "terms")
>>> sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(freq, "freq")
>>> sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM terms JOIN freq ON terms.article_id = freq.article_id AND terms,token = freq.token").show()
+----------+-------------+----+--------+---------+----------+---------+-----+
|article_id|          ner| pos|     sen|    token|article_id|    token|count|
+----------+-------------+----+--------+---------+----------+---------+-----+
|         1| Organisation| NNP|example1|Standford|         1|Standford|    1|
|         1|            O|  VP|example1|       is|         1|       is|    2|
|         1|     LOCATION| ADP|example1|       is|         1|       is|    2|
|         2|Organisation2|NNP2|example2|Standford|         2|Standford|    1|
|         2|           O2| VP2|example2|       is|         2|       is|    1|
|         2|    LOCATION2|ADP2|example2|     good|         2|     good|    1|
+----------+-------------+----+--------+---------+----------+---------+-----+
```

Hope this helps!